# More efficient way to write conditionals with lots of OR operators

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, optimization, conditional-statements

How can I (more) efficiently write out an *if / else* conditional that uses the same variable and a huge amount of OR operators?

I've been banging my head on the desk trying to think of a way around writing out all of these OR operators with the same comparison. *For* loops won't do the trick, and I'm pretty certain that a *do / while* loop wouldn't do it either. A *switch / case* might solve this, but I don't think it could condense the code or make it any less tedious to write out.

The example below illustrates my dilemma. The [uicollectionview](/questions/tagged/uicollectionview) API has a protocol method which is called for each section in the collection and needs a return value for the number of items in that section. Essentially, the protocol method below is a fancy *for* loop.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0 || section == 31) return 7;
    else if (section == 1 || section == 26 || section == 27 || section == 28 || section == 29 || section == 30) return 6;
    else if (section == 2 || section == 3 || section == 4 || section == 5 || section == 6 || section == 7 || section == 8 || section == 9 || section == 10 || section == 11 || section == 12 || section == 13 || section == 14 || section == 15) return 2;
    else if (section == 16 || section == 17 || section == 18 || section == 19 || section == 20 || section == 21 || section == 22 || section == 23 || section == 24 || section == 25) return 4;
    else return 7;
}
```

As you can see in the extremely tedious *if / else* conditional I've written, it checks for *every single section*. I feel like I'm missing something - that Objective-C provides a nifty way around this kind of tedious and inefficient conditional writing / checking?

Comment: You could use a dictionary for these mappings.

Comment: Or even better, don't use static values. Have an array that represents each section. Then just ask the appropriate array how large it is. The code you've shared seems like an attempt to get around using a view model. Don't fight it, view models are awesome.

Comment: Yes, having a proper data structure would solve this. That said, several of your conditional expressions amount to checks that a value is in a range of integers. You could collapse those down to `2 <= section && section <= 15` and `16 <= section && section <= 25`, etc.

Comment: ...or just use NSIndexSex. That's what it's for.

Comment: You're right about using `<=` and `>=` @KenThomases, but this question can also be applied more generally (eg. with strings, dictionaries, etc.).

Comment: @quellish Could you provide a bit more detail on NSIndexSet? Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSIndexSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: It's C so another option for readability is to use #define to define a meaningful term to use instead inside the conditionals. You can then tuck the defines away in a .h file.

Comment: You should use a data structure that's setup for a sectioned collection view as CrimsonChris suggested. If your data was set up as an array of arrays, where each inner array is one section, then the code in numberOfItemsInSection becomes "return [array[section] count];"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean way is to use a `switch` statement. These are usually implemented with a branching array, so are quite efficient.

```
switch (section)
{
case 0:
case 31:
    return 7;
...
}
```

And the most efficient of all (branchless) is a lookup-table:

```
const int nums[]= { 7, 6, 2, 2, 2... };

return nums[section];
```

Comment: I'd recommend using switch.  Cleaner, clearer and easy to comment to describe what you're doing.  Using bitmasks and range collapsing can hide the intent and introduce unintended errors.

Answer (score 1):

`switch` is probably the right answer, but you can also use shift/mask, something like:

```
int sectionBit = 0x00000001 << section;
if (sectionBit & 0x80000001) return 7;
if (sectionBit & 0x7c000002) return 6;
etc
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that it's tedious and error-prone to define the bit constants, but one can sometimes develop the constants by using enums, etc (at the expense of long declaration strings).

Answer (score 1):

A generic approach to this is to use `NSArray` /  `NSDictionary` to build indexes, something like:

```
NSArray *sections = @[@3, @5, @27, ...];
if ([sections containsObject:@3]) ...
```

or

```
NSDictionary *sections = @{ @5: @27, @7: @23, ... };
int value = [sections[@(section)] intValue]
```